# fgets -difference between array size and int num

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[2];
    printf("Enter some things here: ");
    fgets(s, 10, stdin);
//    strrev(s);
    printf("\nText: %s", s);
    printf("\nsize: %d\n", sizeof(s));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%c\n", s[i]);
    return 0;
}

//CONSOLE:
/*Enter some things here: abcdefghiklmn

Text: abcdefghi
size: 2
a
b
  (this is a symbol)



g
h
i

*/
```

A problem using fgets when i make the "INT" that fgets read higher than size of the arra (pic)
So where do other letters go?, what truly happens in the memmory ??
thanks everyone!

**update: 
Tks everyone. Btw, i noticed that regardless of any "string" and size of s (smaller than the "int" - basically just some testing), the output will be 
 1. those that stored in array s 
 2. weird symbol ( maybe it's the "\0" to construc a string ) 
 3. blank blank blank... 
 4. last part of my inputed String before. 
 Is there any concidences here ? Just some curiosity, tks all again ^^

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then provide a [example], please.

Comment: You should use `fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);` unless `s` is dynamically allocated.

Comment: The other letters go past `s` and overwrite the stack, which will probably cause your program to crash.

Comment: Overwriting memory that doesn't belong to you will result in _undefined dbehaviour_ (google that term).

Comment: Two rules about `fgets`: (1) the number you pass as the second argument should always be the size of the memory area pointed to by the first argument.  (2) This number should always be comfortably greater than the longest input line you can reasonably expect.

Comment: This means that if you want to limit the user's input to (say) 2 or 10 characters, the limit you pass to `fgets` is *not* the way to do it.

Comment: Also `sizeof(s)` isn't the length of the string pointed to by `s`. You need the `strlen` function.

Comment: Try `char s[2];
    fgets(s, 10, stdin);` --> `char s[80];
    fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);`

Answer (score 0):

Your string has a size of 2. so it can only collect from the user 1 character because after it, it has to put a '\0' for marking the end of the string.
if you want to put 10 char - try `s[11]`.
like this you can collect 10 chars and then the last char (s[10]) will be '\0' (will be inputed there automatically).